# React-Native & Firebase: How to show notifications?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add notifications to my app using Firebase Functions and firebase-fcm. The goal is to send a notification when a child is added to Firebase Database and I think I installed all correctly because the function appears in the Firebase Console (Functions Tab).

```
sendNewMessageNotification
     ref.write
```

But when I add a child to the database ("/chat") this warning appears and no notification. When I print the content on FCM.on(...) shown below, it receives the correct data, how can I display it in a notification?

```
root
|- chat
    |- -KhaJBhVHD
           |-email: 'example'
           |-message: 'example'
```

**Warning:**

```
 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
    Platform is not defined
    ReferenceError: Platform is not defined
```

**Firebase Functions:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const _ = require('lodash');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/chat').onWrite(event => {
    const getValuePromise = admin.database()
                                 .ref('chat')
                                 .orderByKey()
                                 .limitToLast(1)
                                 .once('value');

    return getValuePromise.then(snapshot => {
        console.log(_.values(snapshot.val())[0]);
        const { message, email } = _.values(snapshot.val())[0];

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'New msg from' + email,
                body: message,
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging()
                    .sendToTopic('chat', payload);
    });
});
```

**Chat Component:**

```
componentDidMount() {               
        FCM.requestPermissions();
        FCM.getFCMToken()
           .then(token => {
               console.log(token)
           });
        FCM.subscribeToTopic('chat');

        FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
            console.log(notif);

            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                switch (notif._notificationType) {
                    case NotificationType.Remote:
                        notif.finish(RemoteNotificationResult.NewData); //other types available: RemoteNotificationResult.NewData, RemoteNotificationResult.ResultFailed
                        break;
                    case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
                        notif.finish();
                        break;
                    case NotificationType.WillPresent:
                        notif.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All); //other types available: WillPresentNotificationResult.None
                        break;
                  }
                }
        });

        FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, token => {
            console.log(token);
        });
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: I just imported Platform and the warning disapeared :) but no notification